# List color is not coming in CSS

Tags: html, css, colors

I wrote this code:

**CSS:**

```
#header {
    margin: 0;
    background:gray;
}

#tabs {
    color:yellow;
    font-weight: bolder;
    display:inline;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header"> 
     <h1>Tabs</h1>
     <ul id="tabs">
         <li id="tabs"><a href="#">This</a></li>
         <li id="tabs"><a href="#">That</a></li>
         <li id="tabs"><a href="#">The Other</a></li>
         <li id="tabs"><a href="#">Banana</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But the yellow font color is not being applied to the `li` items. Why is this happening? And how should I write this code in order to get correct output?

Comment: You have more than one thing with the same ID; that's bad.

Comment: An ID *must* be unique. Use classes instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have multiple elements with the same ID, it'll usually apply to only the first one. Elements should have unique IDs. Use classes instead.

From [The global structure of an HTML document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id):

> The id attribute assigns a unique identifier to an element
>
> The class attribute, on the other hand, assigns one or more class names to an element; the element may be said to belong to these classes. A class name may be shared by several element instances

So your code should look like this:

```
<li class="tabs"><a href="#">This</a></li>
<li class="tabs"><a href="#">That</a></li>
<li class="tabs"><a href="#">The Other</a></li>
<li class="tabs"><a href="#">Banana</a></li>
```

`#` for ID, `.` for class. Multiple elements can have the same class. You also want to change the link color of the `li`s so specify that in the CSS:

```
.tabs a
{
 color:yellow;
 font-weight: bolder;
 display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Anything is not working until and unless, I am removing the `a` tag. How can I do it without removing `a` tag?

Answer (score 4):

Because the text is inside of links. You'll need to specify the color of links inside of tabs like this:

```
#tabs a{color:yellow}
```

for it to work.

Also, don't use the same id twice. You can remove the ids from teh lis if you use the code I provided.

Answer (score 2):

Your `a` tag likely takes precedence. Set it to inherit its color:

```
#tabs {
    color: yellow;
}
#tabs a {
    color: inherit;
}
```

You may also want to set `text-decoration: none;`.

Comment: Adding `#tabs a {
    color: inherit;
}
` is not working. In fact I am forced to remove the whole `a` tag.

Answer (score 2):

For starts you need to take the id's off the `<li>`. ID's are unique.

You're actual problem is you're not targeting the links themselves:

```
#tabs a {
    color: yellow;
}
```

This will let you apply styles to the links rather than the `<ul>`